# How to manipulate how bright an object is based on how much light hits it

Tags: light, lighting

Ok so I've been working on this scene with a bunch of flyers on a wall:
[image: flyer-render-1]

The problem is that the flyers on the wall under the main lightsource feel a little too dim, they should definitly be catching more light and I don't quiet understand why they don't.
Either way I tried to work around this in a couple of ways but both have failed to produce the result I'm looking for.

First I tried rotating the normals of the flyer planes more upwards in order to force them catching the light with following result:[image: flyer-render-2]
The flyers sure did catch some extra light (I probably pushed the normals a little too far), but it coused more issues than it fixed. First the flyers got very desturated, second the flyers on the ground lost light when in reality they probably should be even brighter than the ones on the wall and third the ones on the side wall lost bightness but caused some kind of distorted lighting on the wall it self brightening it...

So I went for another approach and added a birghtness-contrast node to the flyer material and attempted to control it with a light input (though I don't think it actually did anything other then input some static value):[image: node-tree]

This resulted in a slightly better outcome:[image: flyer-render-3]
However as you can see now the flyers on the left side that are in the shadow are far brighter than they should...

As a desperate move I have compsited the first and third render using AffinityPhoto to produce the result I wanted:[image: flyer-render-comp]

However I would like to know if there is a way to achive this result without taking multiple renders or using extrnal software, in an instance that I would like to create an animation for example and run into the same issue.
Basically I'd like to achive my final result with a single render.

Sorry if this ws a bit lenghty.

Scene .blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ry6L-4DBp64dCj5Wpse94yqsFyCF7fjy/view?usp=sharing

Comment: have you tried a contrast node applied to a Object index mask in the compostitor?

Comment: I tried it now and the result is the same as my 3rd outcome, it didn't fix my issue. This was certainly a useful tip though, I didn't know about object indexes before. Doing it this way is far more efficient than messing with the actual materails (I had to adjust 5 of them and rendered preview is much slower than the viewer node). Thanks!

Comment: one other thing you should try is to change the roughness and specular highlights: poster are usually made of plastic paper, which is glossier.

Also, can you provide a .blend file of the scene? It might be helpful to know what lights do you have (for example check that the world lighting is turned off) and what are your settings (have you tried reducing light bounces?).

Also, are you using Cycles or Eevee?

Comment: I've tried playing with specular and roughness before but found that it had neglageble effect, I'm using 4 spotlights for the wall and blenders forest HDRi for world lighting but it's turned down to 0.2 (I essentailly use it for some ambiance). I'm also using cycles. I'm uploading the .blend file to my google drive, I'll add it to the post once it's done.

Comment: Ok I've solved it, In the compositor I used the shadow pass and masked it with object inexes you mentioned so it would only add extra shadow over the flyers, which also allowed me to use a mix node to over expose the flyers in the center. This way I can get the reuslt I want in a single render and it would work for animation. Thanks you again for your input, it's been most helpful.